# PGP encryption with multiple keys in mule

Tags: encryption, mule, pgp

Given that PGP supports encryption using multiple public keys, how it can be achieved in mulesoft?

adding two keys in Public Key Ring File Name field on encryption config window for pgp encrypter tab results in error as `org.mule.module.pgp.exception.MissingPGPKeyException: No key file found in: abc.gpg,test.pgp`

Is it possible to add multiple public keys from this encrypt module or else how it can be done? mule runtime : 3.8.5

much appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using java component- invoking terminal and running gpg encrypt command from java runtime. I am just checking for OS first to build a command string to run its respective terminal

```
boolean isWindows = System.getProperty("os.name")
              .toLowerCase().startsWith("windows");

/*gpg command options may vary as per your requirement. multiple --recipient option here is the way to encrypt with multiple public keys.
Using StringBuilder helps to build this string from input/dynamic values.
*/

String command = "gpg --pgp6 --armor --batch --output encryptedHelloWorld.pgp --trust-model always --recipient "<part of UserID1 (either name or emailId)>" --recipient "<part of UserID2>" --encrypt helloWorld.txt" 

/*in case you need to change directory to where your file is to encrypt it from one command, you could append this
`"cd"+ <your path to file> "&" + command`  ----> for  windows
`"cd"+ <your path to file> ";" + command`  ----> for linux
*/

public int executeCommand(String command) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Process pr;
    if (isWindows) {
        String[] cmd = { "cmd.exe", "/c", command };
        pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    }
    else {
        String[] cmd = { "/bin/sh", "-c", command };
        pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    }           
    int exitStatus = pr.waitFor();  // this gives you value 0 if success or other than 0 which ties to error message
    errorInputStream = pr.getErrorStream(); //streaming error message

    return exitStatus;
}
```